# Local Variables Inefficient in onChronometerTick?

Tags: java, android, performance

This is a chopped down version of my Activity. I have a chronometer, and `onChronometerTick` is called every second. Would it be inefficient to have local variables declared and initialised inside the method?

Or would it be better practice to declare the variables outside of the method and just change their values inside inside `onChronometerTick`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener {


    //Declaring View Variables
    private Chronometer timer; //The timer

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //Initialising View Variables
        timer = ((Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chronometer));
        timer.setOnChronometerTickListener(this);
    }

    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {

        //Local variables
        String timerTime = (chronometer.getText()).toString();  //Gets the string value of the timer

        Boolean stop = false;
        Boolean halfTime = false;
        Boolean fullTime = false;

        switch (timerTime){

            case "00:10":
                stop = true;
                break;

            case "00:20":
                halfTime = true;
                break;
            case "00:30":
                stop = true;
                break;
            case "00:40":
                stop = true;
                fullTime = true;
                break;

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: is it causing any performance issues? On the other hand they are just assigned? use `boolean` instead of `Boolean`

Comment: No it isn't, but i wondered if it was bad practice to set up variables inside of a method that is called lots of times.